# Raspberry PI 3 Increase Gpu Memory to 944

Tags: memory, cpu, gpu, overclocking, memory-split

I use Raspberry PI 3  and wnat to get more GPU memory to work. I overclock my PI to get more performance because I use it for home Apache/PHP/MySQL server, Access Point and somethimes play music and watch youtube videos.

Here is my config.txt setup:

```
dtparam=sd_overclock=100
arm_freq=1300
core_freq=500
over_voltage=4
sdram_freq=575
sdram_schmoo=0x02000020
over_voltage_sdram_p=6
over_voltage_sdram_i=4
over_voltage_sdram_c=4
v3d_freq=500
h264_freq=333
gpu_mem=512
```

Can I use `gpu_mem_1024` or something else to get more GPU memory to video can play better?

For now I have cutting when play videos and that not like.

Also I want to get best performance from this machine.

For cooling I have pwm controled fan and big aluminium cooler.

Here is how my device look:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I would think the more you throw at the GPU, less for the system and it ends up swapping. If anything that might reduce performance overall.

Comment: Can you write me a good setup for overclocking?

Comment: There is a question in your title that is not born out in the body.  It sounds at first as if you are *trying* to make the mem split 50/50 but don't know how -- yet you indicate you've done it properly in `config.txt` and do not claim it has not worked.  Put another way: **I do not see any question here**.  We are not a discussion forum whereby you can explain your set-up and then start querying people tangentially in comments.  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) since you have not yet.

Comment: May be worth reading for you: https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#configtxt It includes details about options for the mem split and overclocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is useless as you don't seem to run GPU RAM heavy OpenGL applications. You don't need more than 128MB GPU RAM to run videos smoothly as the hardware decoder will use only a fixed amount. So increasing it will not fix your issue. On the other hand you are reducing the RAM for the ARM CPU and therefore forcing it to use the Swapfile. This dramatically reduces your CPU performance. I can't believe your system even runs.

Comment: Interesting is that system work perfect. Sometimes I need restart after 5-6 days. Can you tell me what is best perdormance?

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić 32MB of GPU memory is the best for high res videos.

Comment: Running LAMP and Kodi Media server on my RPi3b+. Had to increase default amount of gpu memory to 256Mb, since then no problem at all.